# Generate select options from array and select multiple element by comparing with another array (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

What I want to do is to generate `option` elements for a multiple `select` drop-down from a JavaScript array. Than select each option in the drop-down that is the same as the value in another array (The `results` array in the example).

The problem is that when the results array has multiple elements, the original options get multiplied in the HTML for the number of elements in the results array.

I understand why this is happening, but I cant seem to find a better solution then the one I currently use, which is something like this:

```
var
options = ['Some value', 'Another value', 'Third value', 'Something completely different'],
results = ['Some value', 'Another value'],
selectHtml;

$.each( options, function( index, value ) {
    var option = value;

    $.each( results, function( index, value ) {
        if ( option === value ) {
            selectHtml += '<option selected="selected" value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
        }
        else {
            selectHtml += '<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
        }
    });
});
```

You can find a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wCWyp/

What I want to accomplish is the same thing, but without the multiplication of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an array search.

```
var 
options = ['Some value', 'Another value', 'Third value', 'Something completely different'],
results = ['Some value', 'Another value'],
selectHtml;

$.each( options, function( index, value ) {
    var option = value;
    if (results.indexOf(option) == -1){
        selectHtml += '<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
    } else {
        selectHtml += '<option selected="selected" value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
    }
});

$('#test').html( selectHtml );
```

Answer (score 2):

How about generating the select, and then do

```
 $("#selectId").val(results);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kgJeQ/

```
var options = ['Some value', 
'Another value', 'Third value', 
'Something completely different'],
results = ['Some value', 'Another value'];

$("#selId").empty();
$.each( options, function( index, value ) {
    var text = value;
     $("#selId").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>');
});
$("#selId").val(results);
```

Comment: Yeah, but there are other circumstances forcing me to implement the loop solution.

Comment: Hmm then I severely wasted my time here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are iterating over the `results` array for every element of the `options` array. You can just use the `indexOf` method to determine if the current `option` is in the `results` array:

```
$.each( options, function( index, value ) {
    selectHtml += '<option ' + (results.indexOf(value) > -1 ? 'selected' : '') + ' value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/wCWyp/3/).

However, bear in mind that [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not available in older browsers, so you will probably want to include a polyfill. MDN provides one in the link above.